# why configure many servlet in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

I don't understand why you configure so munch servlet, provided a dispatcherservlet for springmvc, the meaning of other servlet configuration and scenarios

Comment: Please try to be specific about which servlets you are concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring MVC Application, we have only DispatcherServlet as FrontController for trapping all the incoming requests to our Application.

- The DispatcherServlet passes those requests to respective
  handler/controller classes (POJO classes), according to the
  configured HandlerMapping.

***So, there's no point of user-defined servlets in Spring MVC App.***

But, if required you can have multiple DispatcherServlet in your app.

> As DispatcherServlet is very flexible. Not only Spring MVC uses it,
>   but also Spring WS and etc.

In general, we declare multiple dispatcher servlets when we need multiple sets of MVC configuration.

[When do we need multiple Dispatcher Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53533321/when-do-we-need-multiple-dispatcher-servlet/53879456#53879456)