# Is it OK for a HttpServlet to share application context with the Spring DispatcherServlet?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, applicationcontext

I see the following code snippet in the `WebApplicationInitializer.onStartup()`:

```
    // The app context is created here.
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(AppWebConfig.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    // The app context is given to the DispatcherServlet: the new DispatcherServlet(ctx)
    Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    dynamic.setAsyncSupported(true);
    dynamic.addMapping("/");
    dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dynamic.addMapping("*.*");

    // And the app context is given to InitServlet as well: the new InitServlet(ctx)
    Dynamic initServlet = servletContext.addServlet("initServlet", new InitServlet(ctx));
    initServlet.setLoadOnStartup(2);
```

So basically, the `ctx` is shared between the `DispatcherServlet` and the `InitServlet` (this is just a custom HttpServlet).

I am new to Spring and not quite sure about the proper use of various application contexts.

For now, I think each servlet should have its own application context. If there're `beans to be shared`, they should be put in the `Root application context`.

So it seems the author wants to put everything into `a single big` DispatcherServlet application context. Is it OK? Any caveat?

### ADD1

A related link:
[Multiple application context, multiple dispatcher servlets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059307/multiple-application-context-multiple-dispatcher-servlets)

Comment: If your concern is `ServletContext`, then here's food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-shared-variables-and-multithreading/

Comment: @BalusC Thanks. `ServletContext` is not a Spring concept. What I am concerned is the `Spring Application Context`, which is used to hold beans. But that link is very informative.

Answer (score 0):

DispatcherServlet is essentially a servlet. And a Spring application context usually holds a bunch of `singleton` objects. So this question basically boils down to: ***Is it OK for 2 servlets to query their dependent objects from a mutual repository***?

If the 2 servlets serve drastically different purposes, it may be *rational* to put their dependent objects into respective application contexts. But so far I see no strong reason to do that but *a matter of opinion*.